# Apperance settings not staying as set

Tags: python-2.7, pygtk, gtk2

Hoping someone can help me, I have managed to get some screen changes and customization in an app I'm building via gtk_rc_parse which is good but if I change the apperance settings with my app open via the menu it changes all my settings which is annoying.

I'm just wondering if anyone knows how to make it so if apperence setting are change after my app is started that it will not change anything inside my app.

I'm using python 2 on a wheezy Linux install, I know it's old but I started this some time ago and have only just got round to trying to finish it now so do not really want to put to much time into learning the upto date software if I don't have to.

Any help would be great, thanks all.